# phpseclib SFTP failed user authentication

Tags: php, laravel, phpseclib

i'm attempting  to test an SFTP connection thru my web app running on laravel 5.7 framework using phpseclib . This is the authentication code, using only password authentication. The SFTP server is also using IP whitelisting as additional security.

```
                $sftp = new SFTP(env('SFTP_HOST'));
                if (!$sftp->login(env('SFTP_USER'), env('SFTP_PASSWORD'))) {
                    echo $sftp->getLog();
                }
```

Comment: Maybe try `ssh -vvv` when connecting to the server via SSH via the CLI and post that output.

Comment: @neubert have updated the main post with the logs output, do let me know if you need more details, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-vvv` logs almost make me wonder if the server is using multi factor authentication. Like you have to provide both an RSA key and a password. If so you should be able to achieve that thusly:

```
$key = new RSA;
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('/home/forge/.ssh/id_rsa'));

$sftp = new SFTP(env('SFTP_HOST'));
if (!$sftp->login(env('SFTP_USER'), $key, env('SFTP_PASSWORD'))) {
    echo $sftp->getLog();
}
```

The `-vvv` logs also indicate that it's skipping straight to keyboard-interactive auth - that it's not even trying password auth. You can force phpseclib to do keyboard-interactive by doing `$sftp->login(env('SFTP_USER'), ['Password:' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD')])` instead of what you are doing.

Maybe some combination of these two tips will help you out.

Comment: used your method and getting a "Connection closed by server" . suspect is something that changed on the SFTP server or account got locked for too many failed attempts. Will contact them and keep you updated on the results. Thanks very much for the help. @neubert

Comment: @user3364008 - can you post updated phpseclib logs? Like maybe post them in a pastebin.com link and then post the link here. Updated `-vvv` logs might help as well!

Comment: sorry for the late response , the party handling the SFTP server has yet to reset my SFTP account, due to some operating issues on their side. The error the -vvv logs are the same as before and the phpseclibs error message when authenticating through the app simple shows "Connection closed by server" , think something went wrong before it could echo out the getLog() i guess ?

Comment: "_The error the -vvv logs are the same as before and the phpseclibs error message when authenticating through the app simple shows "Connection closed by server"_". What all variations did you try? If you did, indeed, try different variations then the phpseclib / getLogs logs might _look_ the same but they, in fact, shouldn't be.

Comment: @user3364008 - So the way public key authentication works in SSH is...  so there's the private key and the public key. The SSH client sends the public key corresponding to the private key via a NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST packet and then the server tells the client whether or not it has that public key on file (usually, it's stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` If the server responds in the affirmative then the SSH client will then send another NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST packet, this time signing the "exchange hash".

Comment: Your logs only seem to show one NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST packet being sent - the one where the client asks the server if it has that key on file. It appears that the server doesn't, in fact, have that key on file, which almost makes me wonder if you're using the right private key.

Comment: i had provided the RSA public key to the people handling the FTP server before, not too sure why this happens. Would have to confirm with them, they have yet give me a response to my query yet. Will get back to you once they do . thanks so much

Comment: Finally worked after the SFTP account reset ! this did it for me `if (!$sftp->login(env('SFTP_USER'),$key, ['Password:' =>  env('SFTP_PASSWORD')])) `
Thanks so much !